# Rideogram not exporting svg to pdf or png (RStudio)

Tags: r, svg

I've bee trying to make a synteny plot with RIdeogram and it worked with same code and files in another computer but in my computer (windows 10) when I try to export it reports

"Warning message: In checkValidSVG(doc, warn = warn) : This picture was not generated by Cairo graphics; errors may result"

and the files are empty. It creates also an html that includes this

"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

and the code for the image.

I've use this code:

```
install.packages("RIdeogram")
require(RIdeogram)
karyotype_dual_pcul_ranat <- read.csv("cariotipos/karyotype_dual_pcul_ranat.csv", sep = ";")
table(karyotype_dual_pcul_ranat$species)
synteny_pcul_ranat <- read.csv("synteny/synteny_pcul_ranat.csv", sep = ";")
head(synteny_pcul_ranat)
ideogram(karyotype = karyotype_dual_pcul_ranat, synteny = synteny_pcul_ranat)
convertSVG("chromosome.svg", device = "pdf")
```

I've tried updating R and the packages, installing Cairo, changing graphics config from default to Cairo. Also I've tried to make svg images with svglite and it worked well.
Please can anyone give me a hint of what's happening?